# Color QTableView Cell based on value in separate cell

Tags: pyqt5

I would like to format a cell based on the value in another cell. I am using a QTableView populated by a QAbstractModel vis a Pandas Dataframe.

Basically as seen below if the value in a cell in column 1 is 'WE' I would like to format the BackgroundRole in the corresponding cell in column 5.

I greatly appreciate any assistance!

```
class StateModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, imported_dataframe=pd.DataFrame()):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._dataframe = imported_dataframe

    def setDataFrame(self, imported_dataframe):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._dataframe = imported_dataframe
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._dataframe.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._dataframe.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        current_column = index.column()
        current_row = index.row()

        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:

                if current_column == 1:
                    it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), current_column]
                    if it == 'WE':
                        return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)

            if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
                if current_column == 1:
                    it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), current_column]
                    if it == 'WE':
                        return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)

            if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
                table_font = QtGui.QFont('open sans', 12)
                return table_font

            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        header_font = QtGui.QFont('open sans', 14, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        black_color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._dataframe.columns[col])
            if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
                return header_font
```

Comment: If you want to format column 5 depending on the values in column 1, you would need something like `if current_column == 5: it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), 1] ...`. Mind you, since python uses zero-based indexing, so if with column 1 and 5 you mean the first and fifth column, you would need something like `if current_column == 4: it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), 0] ...`

Comment: @Heike You ROCK!...That works perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: What is the appropriate way to accept your answer and give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is exactly what @Heike sugested.

```
    if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
        if current_column == 5:
            it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), 1]
            if it == 'RTP':
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor('#d3b2ff'))
```